# How does $x^2y - xy^2$ become $xy(x-y)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x^2y - xy^2$

```
 |
 |
 V
```

$xy(x-y)$

How does the top one become the bottom one?

Comment: Factorize !    .    .

Comment: The step is not valid in general. You need that multiplication is abelian (or at least that $xy=yx$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'd say you are way overcomplicating this. Or, if you want, you are undercomplicating, because you also need that multiplication is associative and distributive, and that addition is abelian and that the set you are working in is a group for addition so that you have inverses and so on. My point is that there are a lot of implicit assumptions and it's not really helpful to point out just one...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Although that's an important point for arbitrary rings, I don't think it's really relevant to this question.

Comment: It follows from the [Distributive Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property).

Comment: omg, did someone say "Distributive Property"? And here I wasted my time learning factoring, FOIL, and long division.

Answer (score 4):

$x^2y-xy^2
=xxy-xyy
=x(xy)-(xy)y
=xy(x-y)
$

Answer (score 0):

In each term is a common factor $xy$

$$ x^2y-xy^2 =xy(x-y). $$